# child process prints wrong ppid()

Tags: c, linux, fork, pid

In this program, why is child process printing wrong ppid()?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void childprocess()
{
  printf("Child: Hi I am the child process\n");
  printf("Child: My process id is %d\n", getpid());
  printf("Child: My parent is %d\n", getppid());
  printf("Child: I am exiting\n");
}

void parentprocess()
{
   printf("Parent: Hi I am the parent process\n");
   printf("Parent: My process id is %d\n", getpid());
   printf("Parent: My parent is %d\n", getppid());
   printf("Parent: I am exiting\n");
}

int main()
{
    pid_t n = fork();
    if(n<0)
    {
      perror("fork failed:");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(n==0)
       childprocess();
    else
       parentprocess();
}
```

Output:

```
Parent: Hi I am the parent process
Parent: My process id is 21550
Parent: My parent is 7452
Parent: I am exiting
Child: Hi I am the child process
Child: My process id is 21551
Child: My parent is 1810
Child: I am exiting
```

If I re-execute. Sometimes the output is what I expect and sometimes it is unexpected.

Comment: try to add some sleep(); in the parent process and I suppose you'll get what you expect. The issue might be the following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the reason.That was stupid. The parent is ending first, so the child(orphan) is getting adopted by init process.

In my case it is the Upstart with process id 1810.

> Upstart is an event-based replacement for the /sbin/init

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is no guarantee that the scheduler will schedule the son process first. Parent process might terminate before son process is run. And since in Linux every process has a parent process (with exception to swapper process), the orphan child is assigned to init.

You can add a `wait()` so that parent process wait for child process.